# com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define Lcom/google/android/gms/analytics/internal/Command$1;

Tags: android, google-analytics

I am developing android app in Android Studio. I have to add **Google Analytics** in my app and did everything related to that but when I try to run my project I am getting this error:

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:dexDebug
UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define Lcom/google/android/gms/analytics/internal/Command$1
```

If I remove **play-services-analytics** everything works fine

Answer (score 5):

After hours with the same problem i found the answer.

The problem is that you have multiple libs with the same classes inside, so one solution would be to remove the repeating files from one of the libs.

You have to:

1. Open the lib `libGoogleAnalyticsServices.jar` with WinRAR, 7Zip or whatever.
2. Go to `com/google/android/gms/analytics/internal` and delete the files `Command$1.class` and `Command.class`.

Answer (score 0):

Try by adding the following piece of code to your build.gradle file inside the android block

```
       defaultConfig {
            multiDexEnabled true
        }

        dexOptions {
    preDexLibraries = false
   }
```